# Jquery Animation effect for .show method

Tags: jquery, html

The following is the code for a simple animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').hide();
  $('img').show('slow');
});
```

Now What I want to implement is when the element Image is hidden when the page is opened and at the same time the show method will execute and reveal the image but from the left to right.

I need the image to reveal itself from the centre of the image.

Click [here](http://images.techhive.com/images/article/2013/02/maggie-100025304-orig.gif)!

Just like the dogs eye is blinking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/).

This library includes [`$.effect()`](https://jqueryui.com/effect/), which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I guess it helped, silly of me that I din't see that API, Anyway Can I edit the question and improve my question and ask something else?

Comment: Create a new question.